# Hikari CP properties are not working with Multiple datasource configuration in Spring 1.5.18

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hikaricp

We are using multiple datasource configuration in our spring boot app. both dataasources belongs to mysql only.

**Configured multiple data source using:**

https://medium.com/@joeclever/using-multiple-datasources-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data-6430b00c02e7

**pom.xml changes:**

```
<!-- exclude tomcat jdbc connection pool, use HikariCP -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<!-- exclude tomcat-jdbc, Spring Boot will use HikariCP automatically -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
    <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**.properties:**

```
spring.db1.datasource.jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db1?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
spring.db1.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.db1.datasource.username=root
spring.db1.datasource.password=
spring.db1.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=5
spring.db1.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=1

spring.db2.datasource.jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db2?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
spring.db2.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.db2.datasource.username=root
spring.db2.datasource.password=
spring.db2.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=5
spring.db2.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=1
```

**Datasource Bean Config:**

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.db1.datasource")
public DataSource db1DataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}


@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.db2.datasource")
public DataSource db2Source() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

When I start the application, its creating 10 connections of db1 (@Primary datasource) by default but its not considering maximum-pool-size and minimum-idle properties.
Also its not creating connections for db2.

Is there any configuration missed ? please help

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have @Primary

```
@Primary
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.db1.datasource")
public DataSource db1DataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}


@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.db2.datasource")
public DataSource db2Source() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

According to https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html you can define the properties as following

```
spring.db1.datasource.jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db1?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
spring.db1.datasource.username=root
spring.db1.datasource.password=
spring.db1.datasource.maximum-pool-size=5
spring.db1.datasource.minimumIdle=1

spring.db2.datasource.jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db2?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
spring.db2.datasource.username=root
spring.db2.datasource.password=
spring.db2.datasource.maximum-pool-size=5
spring.db2.datasource.minimumIdle=1
```

Also using DataSourceBuilder can auto-detect driver base on the connection string. 
You can define `logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig=TRACE`
 to see that your connection properties work.

Comment: Yes I already mentioned @Primary but not working. And properties you have given are for current version not for 1.5.18

Comment: I don't see any log statements on TRACE level in [HikariConfig](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/blob/f0676c8727f6a5e817686addb82f8ecf83b12b2b/src/main/java/com/zaxxer/hikari/HikariConfig.java#L964). But DEBUG should be sufficient to log the configuration properties.

Answer (score 0):

Look this my solution: https://github.com/dijalmasilva/spring-boot-multitenancy-datasource-liquibase

With this solution you can add more datasources later without having to change the code!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where non-primary DB was not getting connected.

Finally I did the below changes and it worked-
You can define your pool-size and other parameters under
DataSourceProperties for specific DB configuration.

Firstly please check your package structure-

com.example.product.entity.db1

com.example.product.entity.db2

com.example.product.repository.db1

com.example.product.repository.db2

com.example.product.configuration

DB1Configuration

DB2Configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "db1EntityManagerFactory",
    transactionManagerRef="db1TransactionManager",
    basePackages="com.example.product.repository.db1"
        )
public class DB1Configuration 
{

    @Bean(name = "db1DataSourceProperties")
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties db1DataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "db1DataSource")
    public DataSource db1DataSource()
    {
        return db1DataSourceProperties().
                initializeDataSourceBuilder().
                type(HikariDataSource.class).build();

    }


    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "db1EntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean 
    entityManagerFactory(
      EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
      @Qualifier("db1DataSource")DataSource dataSource){

        return builder.dataSource(dataSource)
                      .packages("com.example.product.entity.db1").
                      persistenceUnit("db1").build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name="db1TransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager reconTransactionManager(@Qualifier("db1EntityManagerFactory")EntityManagerFactory reconEntityManagerFactory)
    {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(db1EntityManagerFactory);
    }



}








import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder.Builder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "db2EntityManagerFactory",
    transactionManagerRef ="db2TransactionManager",
    basePackages={"com.exmaple.product.repository.db2"}
        )
public class DB2Configuration 
{
    @Bean(name = "db2DataSourceProperties")
    @ConfigurationProperties("db2.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties db2DataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }


    @Bean(name = "db2DataSource")
    public DataSource db2DataSource()
    {
        return db2DataSourceProperties().
                initializeDataSourceBuilder().
                type(BasicDataSource.class).build();

    }


    @Bean(name = "db2EntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean 
    itmsEntityManagerFactory(final EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder)
    {

      Builder dataSource = builder.dataSource(db2DataSource());
    return dataSource.
      packages("com.example.product.entity.db2").persistenceUnit("db2").build();

    }


    @Bean(name = "db2TransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager itmsTransactionManager(@Qualifier("db2EntityManagerFactory")EntityManagerFactory db2EntityManagerFactory)
    {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(db2EntityManagerFactory);
    }
}


application.properties
spring.datasource.driver = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db1
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root

db2.datasource.driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
db2.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db2
db2.datasource.username=root
db2.datasource.password=root
```